# Setting the id attribute with knockoutjs including a prefix

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using KnockoutJS to iterate over an object, like this:

Now this all works. But the problem i have is that it sets the `id` of the `button` to just a number. So it looks like this:

```
<button id="1">Button 1</button>
<button id="3">Button 2</button>
<button id="8">Button 3</button>
```

So i tried to put a prefix in front of the the 'Id' property, like so:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Items">
    <button data-bind="text: Name, attr: {'id': 'myprefix_' + Id}"></button>
</div>
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. My `id` gets filled with some Knockout observable function when i do it like that...

So my question is, how can i add a prefix when i specify the `id` attribute of a field?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If `Id` is an observable, you must "unwrap" it: `'myprefix_' + Id()`.

Answer (score 75):

Actually used this today - to unwrap the observable I had to do:

```
<button data-bind="attr: { id: 'prefix_' + $index() }"> Send </button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 30):

I think it's best to use the $index for example

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Items">
    <button data-bind="text: Name, attr: {id: 'myprefix_' + $index() }"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I upvoted before I found, at least in my particular case, that I had to use "$index()", not just "$Index".

Answer (score -1):

```
       <img data-bind="event: {click: $root.afficherDetailmembreFamille}" src="ucc/gestion_Famille/images/arbre-fleche-off.png" />

          <label data-bind=" text: nom"></label>
          <label data-bind=" text: prenom, click: $root.afficherDetailmembreFamille"></label>
  <br>

   <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'DivMembreFamille'+id}" style="margin-left: 40px; display: none;">
```