# Dynamically finding the div rendered through the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am using knockout to dynamically create a div and bind array items as follows:

```
<div data-bind="template:{name:'person-template',foreach:$data[1],afterrender:sample}">
```

```
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
<div id="uniqueid">
</div>
</script>
```

I am in confusion as how to generate the unique ids for divs created. Can you one give an idea?

Comment: Maybe `<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'person-row-' + $index }">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [uniqueName](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/uniqueName-binding.html) binding.
Even better the [uniqueId](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/360) binding.

There are other different ways to implement this functionality, as pointed @haim770 and discussed in other threads on SO - [Setting the id attribute with knockoutjs including a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508404/setting-the-id-attribute-with-knockoutjs-including-a-prefix).